# How to compute the reduced words of Coxeter group by Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a new. I have installed Python with chevie package. I don't know how to  compute reduced words of Coxeter group.

I need some references or book about Python with chevie package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically what you're looking for is an algorithm which at each step replaces a subword of the form you are working in/with , and trying to remove an intersection between it and another instance?

Without knowing much more about what exactly you're trying to accomplish in detail I do remember that the preferred decomposition is given by taking the lexicographically smallest (or largest) reduced decomposition.

Also, try to keep in mind that, given if your chosen element is the lexicographically first reduced expression for your permutation, this is how people usually prove that any two reduced expressions for a given permutation are connected by a series of long and short braid moves -- by reducing both to the lexicographically first reduced expression for that permutation.

You can find such an algorithm for the symmetric group e.g. in:

Adriano Garsia, The saga of reduced factorizations of elements of the symmetric group, Publications du Laboratoire de Combinatoire et d' Informatique 29 (2002)

While oddly enough, I don't see this book listed on MathSciNet, I just found a copy available for free by googling: Adriano Garsia saga

This is also discussed (for more general Coxeter groups) in the book:

Anders Björner and Francesco Brenti, Combinatorics of Coxeter groups, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 231, Springer, New York, 2005, xiv + 363 pp.

At least the connectedness result is there, and I believe it is again by this type of algorithm -- I don't have the book with me right now to check for sure.

Another potentially relevant reference is:

Paul Edelman, Lexicographically first reduced words, Discrete Math, 147 (1995), no. 1-3, 95--106.

Math fried my brain, I hope it makes sense to you. If not try the materials provided above. Hope this helps.

Comment: For if you're in the infinite irreducible case. You can also check reducedness using the intervening neighbors property. See http://emis.ams.org/journals/EJC/Volume_17/PDF/v17i1n9.pdf . This may save some effort by easily telling you when you are already reduced as well as giving smaller segments that you know aren't reduced so that the you can feed the algorithm smaller segments first. I'll try it out see if it actually gives a speedup.